# Partially update table from csv

Tags: sql, csv

I am running the following query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE data LIKE customers;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/iban.csv'
INTO TABLE data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(customers_id, customers_banktransfer_iban, customers_banktransfer_bic); 

UPDATE data B
INNER JOIN customers A USING (customers_id)
SET A.customers_id = B.customers_id;
SET A.customers_banktransfer_iban = B.customers_banktransfer_iban;
SET A.customers_banktransfer_bic = B.customers_banktransfer_bic;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE data;
```

The error message I get is:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'customers_banktransfer_iban'
```

Anyone who knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update query should be like this:

```
UPDATE data B
INNER JOIN customers A USING (customers_id)
SET A.customers_id = B.customers_id,
A.customers_banktransfer_iban = B.customers_banktransfer_iban,
A.customers_banktransfer_bic = B.customers_banktransfer_bic;
```

Otherwise you're trying to assign a value to a variable which you haven't declared.